# How to Fix Pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported

Tags: next.js

I have a Next Js app that has pages with getServerSideProps. I'm now trying to npm run build and npm export it so I can get the 'Out' Folder and host it on firebase but in the process of doing so I get the error `pages with "getServerSideProps" can not be exported`

getServerSideProps

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const providers = await getProviders();
  const session = await getSession(context);

  return {
    props: {
      providers,
      session,
    },
  };
}
```

Package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start"
  }
```

Comment: You can't use `getServerSideProps` with `next export`. `getServerSideProps` is used for SSR and requires a running server to work. Either use `next start` or modify your code to be in line with [`next export` limitations](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to export your codebase to static HTML / CSS with `next export`. You can't run this command while any of your pages contain server-rendering logic. Check the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) on static exports.